# how to embed x-axis and y-axis in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I use jupyter notebook.

I succeeded to embed matplotlib graph ,but x-label,y-label, x-axis and y-axis was not embedded.

I can not solve this problem

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
import Tkinter as tk
else:
    import tkinter as tk
    import matplotlib.backends.tkagg as tkagg
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg

def draw_figure(canvas, figure, loc=(0, 0)):
    figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasAgg(figure)
    figure_canvas_agg.draw()
    figure_x, figure_y, figure_w, figure_h = figure.bbox.bounds
    figure_w, figure_h = int(figure_w), int(figure_h)
    photo = tk.PhotoImage(master=canvas, width=figure_w, height=figure_h)

    canvas.create_image(loc[0] + figure_w/2, loc[1] + figure_h/2, image=photo)

    tkagg.blit(photo, figure_canvas_agg.get_renderer()._renderer, colormode=2)


    return photo
w, h = 400, 400
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("the graph of y") 
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=w, height=h)
canvas.pack()


fig = mpl.figure.Figure(figsize=(4,4))
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
ax.plot(x, y,color="red")
ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")

fig_x=50
fig_y=50
fig_photo = draw_figure(canvas, fig, loc=(fig_x, fig_y))
fig_w, fig_h = fig_photo.width(), fig_photo.height()

tk.mainloop()
```

x,y is number input by user

Comment: I don't know what exactly you mean by "embed axes". But if the issue is that you don't see the axes decorators this would be because they are outside the figure. In that case use `ax = fig.add_subplot(111)` instead of  `ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])`.

Comment: OMG genius!!!!!!! thank you for kind and sorry about my english is bad.